# Convert list object to IEnumerable<> in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I built a join query using EF in the controller side.

How can I pass the columns that I need from the controller to the view?

My query is :

```
var unretObj = _unitOfWork.CartsTransaction.GetUnreturnedCarts(branchId, compId)
                          .Join(_unitOfWork.ApplicationUser.GetAll(),
                                ct => ct.UserId,
                                au => au.UserId,
                                (ct, au) => new { ct, au })
                          .Join(_unitOfWork.Lock.GetAll(),
                                ctau => ctau.ct.CartMacId,
                                l => l.MacId,
                                (ctau, l) => new { ctau,l })
                          .Select(result => new
                                            {
                                                result.ctau.ct.UnlockTime,
                                                result.l.LockIdByComp,
                                                result.ctau.au.FullName,
                                                result.ctau.au.PhoneNumber
                                            }).ToList();
```

I created a model class (not mapped to the database) with the columns that I need:

```
[NotMapped]
public class UnreturnedLocks 
{
        public DateTime UnlockTime { get; set; }
        public int LockNumber { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

How can I convert the object `unretObj` to an `IEnumerable<UnreturnedLocks>` so that I can pass it to the view ?

Or is there another way to use the general object in the view without converting it?

Comment: unretObj  is an IEnumerable already (you did ToList to make it, it was an IEnumerable before that too)

Comment: but if i pass unretObj as is to the view i'm getting an exception, i need to cast to IEnumerable<UnreturnedLocks>

Comment: Is this about ASP.NET or entity framework? It seems the latter.

Comment: Can't you just make a`new UnreturnedLocks` instead of the anonymous type? Or will entity framework not accept that?

Comment: @JHBonarius selecting anonymous type allows you to make a custom projection from DB table. If you pass concrete type, it will switch to client-side evaluation and try to convert the `Join` result to `UnreturnedLocks` in memory after fetching all columns from the join table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Select(result => new {...}` will return an `IQueryable` of anonymous objects, you then need to convert them to `IEnumerable<UnreturnedLocks>` like this:

```
...
.Select(result => new
{
    result.ctau.ct.UnlockTime,
    result.l.LockIdByComp,
    result.ctau.au.FullName,
    result.ctau.au.PhoneNumber
})
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(res => new UnreturnedLocks
{
   UnlockTime = res.UnlockTime
   ....
})
.ToList();
```

Alternatively, you can use [Automapper Queryable Extensions](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html)

Comment: @JHBonarius Without `.ToList()` you can encounter 2 errors: 1. `DbContext` can be disposed before you will fetch all results from it. 2. There may be another call to DB based on result enumeration that will throw an exception because you will try to execute a new command before closing this one. So yes, theoretically you are right, it's not required, but in practice, you will get an exception in many scenarios.